# How would you translate the phrase “for myself”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

When I say “for myself” I mean it in a way such as “everything I do is for myself”. How can I phrase this in Latin?

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is to say ***mihi ipsi***, which works independent of your gender.
(Many expressions in Latin look a bit different for men and women.)
In specific contexts there may be better choices of words, but for a general "for myself" or "for the benefit of myself" this will work, and it's also understandable as a motto if you wish to use it so.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibly is to use **Meā causā** which means "for my own sake". To say “everything I do is for myself” we can have: *Quidquid facio, mea causa facio*

Answer (score 2):

Joonas' suggestion, *mihi ipsi,* is good but is somewhat emphatic: 'for me myself'.

I am partial to d_e's suggestion, *mea causa;* it is idiomatic without emphasis.

You might also consider simply *pro me,* a literal translation, on analogy of *pro patria* 'for the fatherland'. It sounds too easy, but it is attested.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is customary to provide at least one attestation. Credibility, for the answer.